# Getting set up with git-buildpackage, pbuilder, etc, for software packaging

Tags: packaging, pbuilder, git-buildpackage

I'm packaging software at work and the scope has increased to have Lucid-based as well as Karmic-based versions. Right now I just build inside a Karmic VM using `git-buildpackage` calling `debuild`, but I've looked into pbuilder so I can do it more easily with chroots, since having one VM for Karmic and another for Lucid seems a little out of place. I've looked around for documentation but it's been very cryptic to me so far. The packages already have git repos set up, it's mostly just the use of pbuilder that's got me stuck.

How can I get this set up easily, preferably to the point where I can script it for other developers here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to configure changeroots that worked for this, so I've been using a lucid vm alongside my karmic vm, building on either as needed.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look as the `pbuilder-dist` script in the [`ubuntu-dev-tools`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-dev-tools) [image: Install ubuntu-dev-tools]
package. It greatly helps with managing multiple pbuilders for different target environments. As an example, to create a Karmic pbuilder run:

```
pbuilder-dist karmic create
```

You can use your newly created Karmic pbuilder with:

```
pbuilder-dist karmic build /path/to/package.dsc
```

The package.dsc can is generated when you build the source package with `git-buildpackage -S`

There is also a `git-pbuilder` wrapper around pbuilder for `git-buildpackage` I have no experience with it. My understanding is that, `DIST=karmic git-pbuilder create` should create you initial Karmic pbuilder. You should then be able to build the package in that pbuilder with:

```
git-buildpackage --git-dist=karmic --git-pbuilder
```

See [`man git-pbuilder`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/git-pbuilder.1.html) and [`man git-buildpackage`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/git-buildpackage.1.html) for more info.

Comment: Will using `-S` still work correctly if it's a package that's built to not have a source tarball included? (closed source). The `dpkg-buildpackage` manpage wasn't clear.

Comment: Based on my testing, `-S` does not work for that case. Is there a way I can change it so that the source is used for pbuilder but dput will not upload it?