# Can I disable Launchpad from making the source of my package available?

Tags: ppa, launchpad

I don't wish that my source code be available for download at launchpad when i upload my packages for building. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The source will *always* be publicly available for any packages you build using Launchpad as a regular user.

What you want is only possible if you get a commercial subscription to Launchpad and use its "private PPA" option ($250/year).

If interested, please see:

- https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+faq/208
- https://launchpad.net/+tour/join-launchpad#commercial

Comment: So how do you make commercial application available for download using apt-get and create debian packages for them

Comment: You Sign up for a commercial subscription... See https://launchpad.net/+tour/join-launchpad#commercial

Comment: Is there any other alternative which is free of cost

Comment: No. If you want to commercialize your project, it's only fair to pay a little for the convenience of Launchpad. Otherwise, the free solution is to create and host your own apt repository.

Comment: However, you can create proprietary software and package it in `.deb` packages without having to pay anything. The software (and project page) just *cannot be hosted on Launchpad* (without a commercial subscription). You can set up your own download server or ship your `.deb` packages to your customers however you like (provided that you are not reusing any code written in your proprietary software in such a way as to [violate its license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft)). Of course, I encourage you to release it as [FOSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software).

Comment: Then I assume that [the WebUpd8 team](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team) got the commercial subscription?

Answer (score 2):

No. See https://help.launchpad.net/Legal/ProjectLicensing.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to build packages without using Launchpad for building by using your own computer.

Among others the `pbuilder` package can be used to build a distribution environment, and then later to build packages.

Here's a link on askubuntu with some details: [Getting set up with git-buildpackage, pbuilder, etc, for software packaging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39690/getting-set-up-with-git-buildpackage-pbuilder-etc-for-software-packaging).

Of course you will have to find a way to distribute the debs that this produces.