# Getting dpkg-buildpackage depencency errors when using apt-get install source --compile

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I was playing around with

```
apt-get install source --compile
```

And I used audacity:

```
sudo apt-get install source --compile audacity
```

However, I am getting a dependency error:

```
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: autoconf automake debhelper (>= 7.0.50~) libasound2-dev libavcodec-dev (>= 4:0.6) libavformat-dev (>= 4:0.6) libavutil-dev (>= 4:0.6) libexpat1-dev libflac++-dev libgtk2.0-dev libid3tag0-dev libjack-dev libmad0-dev (>= 0.14.2b) libmp3lame-dev libogg-dev (>= 1.0.0) libportsmf-dev libsbsms-dev (>= 2.0.0) libsndfile1-dev (>= 1.0.0) libsoundtouch-dev (>= 1.3.1-2) libsoxr-dev (>= 0.0.5) libtwolame-dev (>= 0.3.9) libvorbis-dev (>= 1.0.0-3) libwxgtk2.8-dev portaudio19-dev (>= 19+svn20101113-3~) vamp-plugin-sdk (>= 2.0)    
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
Build command 'cd audacity-2.0.3 && dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc' failed.
E: Child process failed
```

`Unmet build dependencies` Makes me believe `dpkg` is the one with missing dependencies, but I'm really not sure. Installing audacity with

```
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

Works just fine, so I don't think this is audacity's issue.

I've seen this question: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies), but I'm not sure if that applies to this or not.

Comment: I assume that you attempted to install the packages listed under "Unmet build dependencies" (autoconf, automake, debhelper, etc), right?

Comment: @InkBlend Yeah, I tried that and it fixed the problem. Personally I think this was a stupid question. Lets close as too localized.

Answer (score 4):

Build-time dependencies are separate from compile-time dependencies, so you can install them with `apt-get build-dep` audacity.

However as this installs otherwise unnecessary packages, it's common to set up pbuilder, e.g. as explained on https://askubuntu.com/a/39718/129

Comment: Well installing the packages manually solved the problem. I'm not sure I quite understand your answer though. Could you elaborate some?

Comment: 'apt-get build-dep' automates that step of installing the packages manually, but there are other tools like pbuilder or sbuild to further automate & isolate the package building process.

Comment: @ajmitch And what packages are expected to be installed using this command?